# How to make panel header clickable in jsf using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2, web-frontend

```
<p:panel id="ManageAccess" header="ManageAccess">
 <h:outputText value="View Account"></h:outputText>
</p:panel>
```

How to make panel header clickable in jsf using bootstrap.
the above code creates a panel in jsf. How to make the header="ManageAccess" clickable?

Comment: Basically every DOM object that is not covered by another and has at least one pixel is clickable.  Are you referring to even handlers such as `onclick`?

Comment: Effectively, this is not JSF related at all. Client-side it is all pure html, so any **existing**  Q/A for making the client-side html element clickable is a valid answer. Lots of these exist in Stackoverflow. Please check them. And why with 'twitter-bootrap'? Why not with plain javascript? Or jquery (which is already in PrimeFaces where the `p:panelGrid` comes from.